# how to implement oAuth in custom membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `nhibernate` and different databases (depends on the project) to persist data. Because of that I'm using `custom membership provider` with user and roles to `authenticate` login and `authorize` access to certain pages.

Now I want to give option to my new users as well as current users to login using their `social network account`.

I'm aware that `asp.net mvc4` comes with built in `simplemembership provider` which handles this login out of the box, but I have to upgrade my custom membership provider cause I already explain (many databases, not just `microsoft sql`).

Which solution would you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open App_Start\AuthConfig.cs and enable whatever social media authorization that you'd like.

For more details, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx?PageIndex=2